# Jquery adding only one row not 4

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hi there can someone please help me with this code:
So this is the blade

```
       <table class="optionsForm" style="width:100%">
        <thead>
          <tr >
           <th><button  type="button" class="add">Add</button></th>  
           @for($c = 1; $c<=4; $c++)
                <th id="column{{ $c}}">   
                  <input type="text" name="columns[{{ $c }}]"  
                  class="form-control" placeholder="Column {{ $c }} "> 
                </th> @endfor
                 <th><button type="button" style="width: 100px; height: 25px" class="addColumn">Add Column</button></th>

              </tr> 
              </thead> 
              <tbody> @for($r = 1; $r<=4; $r++)
              <tr class="prototype">
```

```
        </tr>  @endfor
                  </tbody>
                </table>
```

and this one is the js code, I need to be able to add only one row, here it is adding 4 rows, I need first to be shown 4 rows, but than when I click add I need to be added only one row how can I achieve this can someone please help me with this thing I am stuck, thank you so much for any efforts.

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
    var id = 0;
    // Add button functionality
    $("table.optionsForm button.add").click(function () {
        id++;
        var master = $(this).parents("table.optionsForm");
        // Get a new row based on the prototype row
        var prot = master.find(".prototype").clone();
        prot.attr("class", "")
        prot.find(".id").attr("value", id);
        master.find("tbody").append(prot);
    });

    // Remove button functionality
    $("table.optionsForm button.remove").on("click", function () {
        $(this).parents("tr").remove();

    });

    $("table.optionsForm button.addColumn").click(function () {
        var $this = $(this), $table = $this.closest('table')


        $('<th><input type="text" name="options"   class="form-control" placeholder="Column"></th>').insertBefore($table.find('tr').first().find('th:last'))

        var idx = $(this).closest('td').index() + 1;
        $('<td><input type="radio" name="col' + idx + '[]" value="" /</td>').insertBefore($table.find('tr:gt(0)').find('td:last'))
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The add button code is creating a collection of four elements with class "prototype" and then cloning four elements:

```
var prot = master.find(".prototype").clone()
```

To add a single element, try selecting the first DOM element from the collection and converting it to a JQuery object before applying `clone`:

```
 var prot = $(master.find(".prototype")[0]).clone()
```

---

As a minimal test/demonstration case (not using blade)

```js
var master = $("#master");
var prot = $(master.find(".prototype")[0]).clone();
master.append(prot);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="master">
<span class="prototype">proto 1</span><br>
<span class="prototype">proto 2</span><br>
<span class="prototype">proto 3</span><br>
<span class="prototype">proto 4</span><br>
</div>
```